# How to use AudioTrim to delete the silences?

Tags: sound

I have an audio file named [del_silences.wav](https://wolfr.am/mSeG89Up).
I want to delete the silence intervals.
But using `AudioTrim`, the audio almost has no change:

```
a = Audio@"https://wolfr.am/mSeG89Up";
Column[{AudioPlot@a, AudioPlot@AudioTrim@a}]
```

[image]

But I want to delete the red region:

[image]

So how to delete the silence intervals that start and end in audio file?

**Ps:I define this function,but it has some limits**

```
myAudioTrim[audio_, val_] := Module[{interval = AudioIntervals[audio, #RMSAmplitude < val &]}, 
    If[Length[interval] >= 2, 
       AudioTrim[audio, Flatten[interval[[{1, -1}]]][[2 ;; -2]]], 
       AudioTrim[audio, {interval[[1, 2]], Duration@audio}]]]

a = Audio@"https://wolfr.am/mSeG89Up";
AudioPlot@myAudioTrim[a, 0.01]
```

[image]

But it has problem,for example:

```
mono = AudioPad[AudioGenerator["Sin", .1], {0.05, 0}];
AudioPlot[mono]
AudioPlot@myAudioTrim[mono, 0.01]
```

[image]

It doesn't delete all the silence.Then I find the problem is the `AudioIntervals`:

```
AudioIntervals[AudioPad[AudioGenerator["Sin", .1], {0.05, 0}], #RMSAmplitude < 0.01 &]
```

> {{0., 0.02322}}
>   expect {{0.,0.05}}

```
AudioIntervals[AudioPad[AudioGenerator["Sin", .01], {0.005, 0}], #RMSAmplitude < 0.01 &]
```

> {}
>   expect {{0.,0.005}}

even using `PartitionGranularity` it can not get the result.

```
AudioIntervals[AudioPad[AudioGenerator["Sin", .01], {0.005, 0}], 
               #RMSAmplitude < 0.01 &, 
               PartitionGranularity -> Quantity[0.1, "Milliseconds"]]
(*{}*)
```

What happened,how to improve this function?

Comment: What's wrong with running `AudioPlot@AudioTrim[data, {1.1, 9.9}]`?

Comment: You can identify the silences using AudioIntervals (which can take a volume threshold), and use the output in AudioTrim.

Comment: @Szabolcs Yeah,I got it.Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we can define a function:

```
myAudioTrim[audio_, val_] := AudioTrim[audio, Flatten[
AudioIntervals[audio, #RMSAmplitude < val &][[{1, -1}]]][[2 ;; -2]]]
```

And then,we can plot the result:

```
a = Audio@"E:\\test.wav"; 
AudioPlot@myAudioTrim[a, 0.01]
```

[image]