# Identifying Silence in Audio

Tags: sound

I have some audios that contain short spaces of silence with different periods of time.

Looking for information, I found this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/129951/how-to-use-audiotrim-to-delete-the-silences).

The [audio example](https://wolfr.am/mSeG89Up) is this.

**Is there a way the program can do the following sequence below?**

1 - Identify periods of silence

2 - Measure the silence period in seconds

3 - Convert all periods of silence to 1 second

```
a = Audio@"https://wolfr.am/mSeG89Up";
Column[{AudioPlot@a, AudioPlot@AudioTrim@a}]
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Import the subject audio:

```
aud = Import["http://home.ustc.edu.cn/~xiaozh/SE/del_silences.wav"]
```

Identify silences:

```
silences = AudioIntervals[aud, #RMSAmplitude < 0.005 &];
```

Split the Audio object at the identified beginning and ends of the silence:

```
splitAuds = AudioSplit[aud, Flatten[silences]];
```

Lengthen the silences (by replacing them with silence of the correct length - there's no need to waste computation for AudioTimeStretch if we know we want silence):

```
lengthenedSilences = MapIndexed[If[OddQ[#2[[1]]], 
  Audio[ConstantArray[0., QuantityMagnitude[AudioSampleRate[aud]]], 
    SampleRate -> AudioSampleRate[aud]],#1] &, splitAuds];
```

*Note that I'm using the nice alternating pattern of noise and silence to decide what to replace.

Now reassemble the Audio object:

```
result = AudioJoin[lengthenedSilences]
```

*You can of course play with the threshold used at the beginning to better define what "silence" is.

Comment: It was fantastic. I just updated your answer by refining the RMSAmplitude value.
I did this because some breathing pauses should not be changed. With this refinement, I successfully achieved my goals. I was very happy with your help.