# Softening Strident Sounds

Tags: sound

I asked a [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/160495/identifying-silence-in-audio) that was very well resolved by [kjosborne](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/49349/kjosborne)

I have some audios that I am looking for better the quality.

Now I'm looking for a solution to soften the sound of `"s"`, which we can find in `space`, `station`, `square`, ...

It seems very strident to me and I wish they were smoothed.

The link to the audio is this (If someone is having trouble accessing the file, let me know):

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N3vQzsB1t222JXB2Sxze9yycEJdyHH2Y/view?usp=drivesdk

```
a = Audio@"https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N3vQzsB1t222JXB2Sxze9yycEJdyHH2Y/view?usp=drivesdk";
Column[{AudioPlot@a, AudioPlot@AudioTrim@a}]
```

Comment: You could try a LowpassFilter and see if that corresponds to what you hear as strident.

Comment: As soon as I can, I'll try. I also thought it might be an option.

Comment: A [de-esser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De-essing) will do that for you. How difficult that is to implement that in Mathematica I don't know.